# PHP: multiple SQL queries in one mysql_query statement

Tags: php, sql, mysql

So I have an SQL dump file that needs to be loaded using mysql_query(). Unfortunately, it's not possible to execute multiple queries with it.

-> It cannot be assumed that the **mysql command-line client** (mysql --help) is installed -- for loading the SQL file directly

-> It cannot be assumed that the **mysqli** extension is installed

```
/* contents of dump.sql, including comments */
DELETE FROM t3 WHERE body = 'some text; with semicolons; scattered; throughout';
DELETE FROM t2 WHERE name = 'hello';
DELETE FROM t1 WHERE id = 1;
```

The explode() below won't work because some of the dump content's values contain semicolons.

```
$sql = explode(';', file_get_contents('dump.sql'));
foreach ($sql as $key => $val) {
    mysql_query($val);
}
```

What's the best way to load the SQL without modifying the dump file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have more problem cases than just semicolons within strings.

- Script [builtin](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-commands.html) commands that cannot be executed by `mysql_query()`, like `USE`.
- Statements that are not terminated with a semicolon, like [`DELIMITER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-programs-defining.html).
- Statements that contain semicolons, but not inside quotes, like `CREATE PROCEDURE`.

I don't know of an easy way to handle this task, without shelling out to the mysql command-line client.  I realize you said you can't rely on that client being present, but without that client, you need a large amount of PHP code to parse the script and execute statements appropriately.

You may be able to find such code inside the [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) product.  However, that product is licensed under the GPL, so if you use any of the code, you must also license your own project under the GPL.

---

See also my answers to these related questions:

- [Running MySQL *.sql files in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027769/running-mysql-sql-files-in-php/4028289#4028289)
- [Loading .sql files from within PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147821/loading-sql-files-from-within-php/149456#149456)
- [is it possible to call a sql script from a stored procedure in another sql script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547915/is-it-possible-to-call-a-sql-script-from-a-stored-procedure-in-another-sql-script/548119#548119)

Answer (score 5):

Occam's razor strikes again.

The above explode() function wasn't going to work because there are semicolons in the values. However, what I failed to realize (and mention) is that semicolons always preceed newlines in the SQL dump file. Alas,

```
$sql = explode(";\n", file_get_contents('dump.sql'));
foreach ($sql as $key => $val) {
    mysql_query($val);
}
```

Also, thanks for your help, Bill.

Comment: You do have cases of semicolon at the end of a line, but it isn't the end of a statement, e.g. inside the body of a procedure or trigger definition.  And statements like DELIMITER that don't end in a semicolon.

Answer (score 3):

There is a bigger issue here. You might have statements that rely on other statements. You can't just execute them linearly blindly.

Comment: Could always tell mysql to ignore unique checks and foreign key checks before running your list of queries which would resolve many issues with query order.

Comment: Right, tell the database to ignore the sanity checks implemented to preserve data integrity, That's a sure fire way to succeed.

Comment: @enobrev: And what would happen if you turn sanity checking back on afterwards? exactly; more problems.

Comment: depending on what you're importing, turning off sanity checks isn't so dire.  Sure if we're talking inserts, it's a problem but if all you're doing is altering the structure, then all those sanity checks are going to go bananas every time you try to remove a table that has incoming references.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//STATIC QUERY
$sql1 = "
CREATE TABLE tblTable (
strOne VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
strTwo VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
strThree VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO tblTable
(strOne, strTwo, strThree)
VALUES ('String 1', 'String 2', 'String 3');
UPDATE tblTable
SET
strOne = 'String One',
strTwo = 'String Two'
WHERE strThree = 'String 3';
"; 
//GET FROM FILE
$sql2 = file_get_contents('dump.sql');
$queries = preg_split("/;+(?=([^'|^\\\']*['|\\\'][^'|^\\\']*['|\\\'])*[^'|^\\\']*[^'|^\\\']$)/", $sql);
foreach ($queries as $query){
   if (strlen(trim($query)) > 0) mysql_query($query);
}
?>
```