# is it possible to call a sql script from a stored procedure in another sql script?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, scripting

I'd like to use . to call sql script from inside a stored proc like so...

```
delimiter ///
create procedure append_procedure()
BEGIN
\. test.sql;    
END; ///
delimiter ;
```

I'm getting a "failed to open 'test.sql;' " error when I run it this way.  I've also tried ! but then I get a permission denied error.  However, I can't eliminate the ; or the whole thing is broken. Is there a way around this?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a set of commands that are builtin to the mysql client.  They're documented under "[`mysql` Commands](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-commands.html)."  These include DELIMITER, SOURCE, HELP, CONNECT, USE, QUIT, etc.

The `\.` (or `SOURCE`) command is one of these builtins.  **You can't execute these builtin commands programmatically, nor from within a stored procedure.**

It'd be like trying to run a UNIX shell builtin from a C program using `execl()`.

A different analogy might be in a web browser, where you can type in special requests like "`about:`" that are handled by the browser app itself; these don't result in any HTTP request to a remote web site.

Also, it wouldn't help if you could source a script from within a stored procedure, because the script itself likely contains a bunch of commands that are mysql client builtins, and thus cannot be run by the stored proc.

---

See also my answers to these related questions:

- [Running MySQL *.sql files in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027769/running-mysql-sql-files-in-php/4028289#4028289)
- [Loading .sql files from within PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147821/loading-sql-files-from-within-php/149456#149456)
- [PHP: multiple SQL queries in one mysql_query statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345637/php-multiple-sql-queries-in-one-mysql-query-statement/345712#345712)

Comment: so, are you saying that there is no way to do this?  or that I just can't do it using \.?

Comment: There is no way for a stored proc to source a script, nor to run many of the commands in the script even if you could source it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Sql Sevrer 2005 you can use the xp_cmdshell command.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046(SQL.90).aspx

Or

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Administering/scriptscheduling/450/

Comment: but i think he wants it for mysql

Comment: yeah, I'm tied to mySQL unfortunately.

Comment: @GeniaS. I highly doubt the 3K to 15K license for Microsoft SQL Server is worth the capability of calling a script from a stored procedure... (and, having used MS SQL Server even more than MySQL but being experienced with both: 
there aren't any other features that are worth the price tag, or the requirement to run on an expensive Windows server OS)