# import sql via php

Tags: php, mysql, import

This may be obvious, but I have exported a database via phpmyadmin to a .sql file.  I'm trying to import the file into another database via a php script, but I can't figure out how to do this.  I'm sure it's easy to do since i can easily accomplish the same thing by running the query through phpmyadmin.  Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a duplicate question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147821/loading-sql-files-from-within-php

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to import .sql file in mysql database using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19751354/how-to-import-sql-file-in-mysql-database-using-php)

Answer (score 7):

You can run mysql command using [system()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) function of php.

You can not do with [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) as this function can not run multiple queries

```
system('mysql -u <user> -p<password> dbname < filename.sql');
```

Answer (score 3):

I wrote this code and it worked for me. Hope it helps.

**Note:** It seems a bit too simple, could anyone, please, warn me if I'm overlooking something? Thanks

```
$connection = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $databaseName);

$query = "";

foreach ($sqlFileContents as $line) {
  $line = trim($line);

  if ($line != "" && substr($line, 0, 2) != '--') {
    $query .= $line;

    if (substr($line, -1) == ';') {
      $connection->query($query);

      echo ($query."\n");

      if ($connection->errno) {
        echo ("\n".$connection->errno . ": ");
        echo ($connection->error."\n");
      }

      $query = "";
    }
  }
}

unset ($line);

if ($connection->errno) {
  echo ($connection->errno . ": ");
  echo ($connection->error);
}

$connection->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>If it's a giant SQL file, all you need to do is</strike>

```
$sql = file_get_contents('sqlfile.sql');
//make the connection
mysql_query($sql); //assuming what you have is actually valid SQL
```

Just curious, why not just do this through a DB utility?

**EDIT** : As Shakthi Singh points out, you can't run multiple queries in `mysql_query` in one go (not tested though).

However, Depending on your file this might still cause problems as talked about in this question : [PHP: multiple SQL queries in one mysql_query statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345637/php-multiple-sql-queries-in-one-mysql-query-statement) (Some statments not being supported by `mysql_query`)

So depending on how your SQL looks the above solution might no be viable.

All is not lost however, this thread : [Loading .sql files from within PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147821/loading-sql-files-from-within-php#149456) talks about a few alternatives. User arin sarkissian points out that [`mysqli_multi_query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) is an option

Comment: @Shakti Singh good point. I've clarified my answer to take this into account

Answer (score 1):

A very nice answer:

[Best practice: Import mySQL file in PHP; split queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883079/best-practice-import-mysql-file-in-php-split-queries/2011454#2011454)

all you need to add here is an upload function

Answer (score 0):

Read in the file, then

```
mysql_query(file_contents)
```

Beware the timeoutwock, my son.

Comment: @Shakti Singh: How do SQL injection attacks against PHP using `;` to terminate a query and start a new one work then? [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) would have no effect on a web site using the mighty `mysql_query`...

Comment: I'm not talking about SQL injection here. As stated in manual `mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported)`. OR you could try by yourself if it works.

Comment: @Shakti Singh: just tried it. Worked fine; only got results for the first query, but the later ones executed. I think the documentation is either for a newer version of PHP or full of it.