# How do I import a .sql file in mysql database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to import a .sql file through PHP code. However, my code shows this error:

```
There was an error during import. Please make sure the import file is saved in the same folder as this script and check your values:

MySQL Database Name:    test
MySQL User Name:    root
MySQL Password: NOTSHOWN
MySQL Host Name:    localhost
MySQL Import Filename:  dbbackupmember.sql
```

And this is my code:

```
<?php
//ENTER THE RELEVANT INFO BELOW
$mysqlDatabaseName ='test';
$mysqlUserName ='root';
$mysqlPassword ='';
$mysqlHostName ='localhost';
$mysqlImportFilename ='dbbackupmember.sql';
//DONT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
//Export the database and output the status to the page
$command='mysql -h' .$mysqlHostName .' -u' .$mysqlUserName .' -p' .$mysqlPassword .' ' .$mysqlDatabaseName .' < ' .$mysqlImportFilename;
exec($command,$output=array(),$worked);
switch($worked){
    case 0:
        echo 'Import file <b>' .$mysqlImportFilename .'</b> successfully imported to database <b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b>';
        break;
    case 1:
        echo 'There was an error during import. Please make sure the import file is saved in the same folder as this script and check your values:<br/><br/><table><tr><td>MySQL Database Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL User Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlUserName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Password:</td><td><b>NOTSHOWN</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Host Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlHostName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Import Filename:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlImportFilename .'</b></td></tr></table>';
        break;
}
?>
```

What am I doing wrong? The SQL file is in the same directory.

Comment: Are you sure `dbbackupmember.sql` file exists in the same directory as your script? What does `var_dump( file_exists('dbbackupmember.sql') );` output?

Comment: yes this is same directory but i dont knw why it is showing error

Comment: Does the apache process have access to the folder/file the dump is stored in? Does `exec('whoami')` return your username? Sometimes exec doesn't work right with the apache process as well because of permissions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading .sql files from within PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147821/loading-sql-files-from-within-php)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I import an SQL file using the command line in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-do-i-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql)

Answer (score 150, accepted):

> **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.
>   Whenever possible, importing a file to MySQL should be delegated to MySQL client.

I have got another way to do this, try this

```
<?php

// Name of the file
$filename = 'churc.sql';
// MySQL host
$mysql_host = 'localhost';
// MySQL username
$mysql_username = 'root';
// MySQL password
$mysql_password = '';
// Database name
$mysql_database = 'dump';

// Connect to MySQL server
mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_username, $mysql_password) or die('Error connecting to MySQL server: ' . mysql_error());
// Select database
mysql_select_db($mysql_database) or die('Error selecting MySQL database: ' . mysql_error());

// Temporary variable, used to store current query
$templine = '';
// Read in entire file
$lines = file($filename);
// Loop through each line
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
// Skip it if it's a comment
if (substr($line, 0, 2) == '--' || $line == '')
    continue;

// Add this line to the current segment
$templine .= $line;
// If it has a semicolon at the end, it's the end of the query
if (substr(trim($line), -1, 1) == ';')
{
    // Perform the query
    mysql_query($templine) or print('Error performing query \'<strong>' . $templine . '\': ' . mysql_error() . '<br /><br />');
    // Reset temp variable to empty
    $templine = '';
}
}
 echo "Tables imported successfully";
?>
```

This is working for me

Comment: Dude! Saved my life! :D As I had huge dump files, I needed to stream the file instead of reading it all at once… see here `http://stackoverflow.com/a/13246630/1050264`

Comment: I added this: if(substr($line,0,2) == "/*"){continue;} as well. Helped.

Comment: don't use this as you will be out of memory in no time!

Comment: @Enrique can you elaborate more to me :D
what should i do first, upload file .sql then keep continue script above !
my question is database update or replace with new one

Comment: @FreddySidauruk you should upload the file and put in same folder where script will be. Then execute the script. Database should be empty, unless you're sure the .sql file will update correctly everything in the database, tables, views, etc.

Comment: Why database should be empty, your script doesn't update auto

Comment: I just had to change all `mysql_` to `mysqli_` and provide the connection argument... And it worked like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Comment: PHPMyAdmin would not import a 24MB table, but this did the trick; much gratitude

Answer (score 57):

You can use the mysqli multi_query function as below:

```
$sql = file_get_contents('mysqldump.sql');

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "pass", "testdb");

/* execute multi query */
$mysqli->multi_query($sql);
```

Comment: This is a whole lot faster than the accepted answer. A 100 times faster to be exact. (I measured it).

Comment: If for some reason you can't use command line `mysql` command, then this is the preferred option. Be careful when using multi_query because it is asynchronous and you must run a blocking loop afterwards.

Comment: To add on to what Dharman said, the catch with this is you need to be able to read the entire dump file into memory for this to work, so it only works with **smaller files**. If you have, say, a 1GB dump file, this will fail due to lack of memory. Large dump files can only be handled via the MySQL command line

Answer (score 39):

> **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.
>   Whenever possible, importing a file to MySQL should be delegated to MySQL client.

the answer from Raj is useful, but (because of file($filename))
it will fail **if your mysql-dump not fits in memory**

If you are **on shared hosting** and there are **limitations** like 30 MB and 12s Script runtime and you have to **restore a x00MB mysql dump**, you can use this script:

it will walk the dumpfile query for query, if the script execution deadline is near, it saves the current fileposition in a tmp file and a automatic browser reload will continue this process again and again ...
If an error occurs, the reload will stop and an the error is shown ...

if you comeback from lunch your db will be restored ;-)

**the noLimitDumpRestore.php:**

```
// your config
$filename = 'yourGigaByteDump.sql';
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUser = 'user';
$dbPass = '__pass__';
$dbName = 'dbname';
$maxRuntime = 8; // less then your max script execution limit


$deadline = time()+$maxRuntime; 
$progressFilename = $filename.'_filepointer'; // tmp file for progress
$errorFilename = $filename.'_error'; // tmp file for erro

mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass) OR die('connecting to host: '.$dbHost.' failed: '.mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbName) OR die('select db: '.$dbName.' failed: '.mysql_error());

($fp = fopen($filename, 'r')) OR die('failed to open file:'.$filename);

// check for previous error
if( file_exists($errorFilename) ){
    die('<pre> previous error: '.file_get_contents($errorFilename));
}

// activate automatic reload in browser
echo '<html><head> <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="'.($maxRuntime+2).'"><pre>';

// go to previous file position
$filePosition = 0;
if( file_exists($progressFilename) ){
    $filePosition = file_get_contents($progressFilename);
    fseek($fp, $filePosition);
}

$queryCount = 0;
$query = '';
while( $deadline>time() AND ($line=fgets($fp, 1024000)) ){
    if(substr($line,0,2)=='--' OR trim($line)=='' ){
        continue;
    }

    $query .= $line;
    if( substr(trim($query),-1)==';' ){
        if( !mysql_query($query) ){
            $error = 'Error performing query \'<strong>' . $query . '\': ' . mysql_error();
            file_put_contents($errorFilename, $error."\n");
            exit;
        }
        $query = '';
        file_put_contents($progressFilename, ftell($fp)); // save the current file position for 
        $queryCount++;
    }
}

if( feof($fp) ){
    echo 'dump successfully restored!';
}else{
    echo ftell($fp).'/'.filesize($filename).' '.(round(ftell($fp)/filesize($filename), 2)*100).'%'."\n";
    echo $queryCount.' queries processed! please reload or wait for automatic browser refresh!';
}
```

Comment: Your script has solved my problem too! I had 2.4GB large SQL and no control over increasing allowed file size and query size. Thanks a ton!

Comment: this could do with an update to mysqli- mysql_connect was deprecated in php 5.5 and removed in 7

Comment: With this script i had problems with some special chars (ö,ä,²,³..) But not in each table. With ManojGeek script above it works fine.

Comment: @user2355808 - thats strange - because booth scripts uses the same functionality and no charset-agnostic-functions  (file and mysql-query vs. fgets and mysql-query) , maybe your db-creation was different

Comment: Be aware of the client-side cache. Also, refresh time can be set to 1 because the timer is not running until the page is loaded.

Answer (score 12):

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$uname = "root";
$pass = "";
$database = "demo1"; //Change Your Database Name
$conn = new mysqli($host, $uname, $pass, $database);
$filename = 'users.sql'; //How to Create SQL File Step : url:http://localhost/phpmyadmin->detabase select->table select->Export(In Upper Toolbar)->Go:DOWNLOAD .SQL FILE
$op_data = '';
$lines = file($filename);
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
    if (substr($line, 0, 2) == '--' || $line == '')//This IF Remove Comment Inside SQL FILE
    {
        continue;
    }
    $op_data .= $line;
    if (substr(trim($line), -1, 1) == ';')//Breack Line Upto ';' NEW QUERY
    {
        $conn->query($op_data);
        $op_data = '';
    }
}
echo "Table Created Inside " . $database . " Database.......";
?>
```

Comment: thank you very much, saving my time. and your code perfectly work for me

Answer (score 10):

```
<?php
system('mysql --user=USER --password=PASSWORD DATABASE< FOLDER/.sql');
?>
```

Comment: This is the recommended solution. Importing a file to MySQL should be always delegated to MySQL client.

Answer (score 4):

Grain Script is superb and save my day. Meanwhile mysql is depreciated and I rewrote Grain answer using PDO.

```
    $server  =  'localhost'; 
    $username   = 'root'; 
    $password   = 'your password';  
    $database = 'sample_db';

    /* PDO connection start */
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server; dbname=$database", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);         
    $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");     
    /* PDO connection end */

    // your config
    $filename = 'yourFile.sql';

    $maxRuntime = 8; // less then your max script execution limit


    $deadline = time()+$maxRuntime; 
    $progressFilename = $filename.'_filepointer'; // tmp file for progress
    $errorFilename = $filename.'_error'; // tmp file for erro



    ($fp = fopen($filename, 'r')) OR die('failed to open file:'.$filename);

    // check for previous error
    if( file_exists($errorFilename) ){
        die('<pre> previous error: '.file_get_contents($errorFilename));
    }

    // activate automatic reload in browser
    echo '<html><head> <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="'.($maxRuntime+2).'"><pre>';

    // go to previous file position
    $filePosition = 0;
    if( file_exists($progressFilename) ){
        $filePosition = file_get_contents($progressFilename);
        fseek($fp, $filePosition);
    }

    $queryCount = 0;
    $query = '';
    while( $deadline>time() AND ($line=fgets($fp, 1024000)) ){
        if(substr($line,0,2)=='--' OR trim($line)=='' ){
            continue;
        }

        $query .= $line;
        if( substr(trim($query),-1)==';' ){

            $igweze_prep= $conn->prepare($query);

            if(!($igweze_prep->execute())){ 
                $error = 'Error performing query \'<strong>' . $query . '\': ' . print_r($conn->errorInfo());
                file_put_contents($errorFilename, $error."\n");
                exit;
            }
            $query = '';
            file_put_contents($progressFilename, ftell($fp)); // save the current file position for 
            $queryCount++;
        }
    }

    if( feof($fp) ){
        echo 'dump successfully restored!';
    }else{
        echo ftell($fp).'/'.filesize($filename).' '.(round(ftell($fp)/filesize($filename), 2)*100).'%'."\n";
        echo $queryCount.' queries processed! please reload or wait for automatic browser refresh!';
    }
```

Comment: I think you and grain need an unlink for the filepointer file after completion don't you? Otherwise it will just keep trying to run from that final pointer if you re-upload the same filename

Answer (score 3):

I have Test your code, this error shows when you already have the DB imported or with some tables with the same name, also the Array error that shows is because you add in in the exec parenthesis, here is the fixed version:

```
<?php
//ENTER THE RELEVANT INFO BELOW
$mysqlDatabaseName ='test';
$mysqlUserName ='root';
$mysqlPassword ='';
$mysqlHostName ='localhost';
$mysqlImportFilename ='dbbackupmember.sql';
//DONT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
//Export the database and output the status to the page
$command='mysql -h' .$mysqlHostName .' -u' .$mysqlUserName .' -p' .$mysqlPassword .' ' .$mysqlDatabaseName .' < ' .$mysqlImportFilename;
$output=array();
exec($command,$output,$worked);
switch($worked){
    case 0:
        echo 'Import file <b>' .$mysqlImportFilename .'</b> successfully imported to database <b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b>';
        break;
    case 1:
        echo 'There was an error during import.';
        break;
}
?>
```

Comment: This is the recommended solution. Importing a file to MySQL should be always delegated to MySQL client.

Answer (score 2):

### If you need a User Interface and if you want to use PDO

Here's a simple solution

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="db" placeholder="Databasename" />
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $query = file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $dbname = $_POST['db'];
    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname","root","");
    $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
    if($stmt->execute()){
        echo "Successfully imported to the $dbname.";
    }
}
?>
```

Definitely working on my end. Worth a try.

Comment: Are you sure this would work with more than a single query? Also, what's the benefit of using prepared statements without any parameters?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PHP version 7 or higher, try below script,

```
// Name of the file
$filename = 'sql.sql';
// MySQL host
$mysql_host = 'localhost';
// MySQL username
$mysql_username = 'username';
// MySQL password
$mysql_password = 'password';
// Database name
$mysql_database = 'database';
// Connect to MySQL server
$con = @new mysqli($mysql_host,$mysql_username,$mysql_password,$mysql_database);
// Check connection
if ($con->connect_errno) {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $con->connect_errno;
   echo "<br/>Error: " . $con->connect_error;
}
// Temporary variable, used to store current query
$templine = '';
// Read in entire file
$lines = file($filename);
// Loop through each line
foreach ($lines as $line) {
// Skip it if it's a comment
if (substr($line, 0, 2) == '--' || $line == '')
    continue;
// Add this line to the current segment
$templine .= $line;
// If it has a semicolon at the end, it's the end of the query
if (substr(trim($line), -1, 1) == ';') {
// Perform the query
$con->query($templine) or print('Error performing query \'<strong>' . $templine . '\': ' . $con->error() . '<br /><br />');
    // Reset temp variable to empty
    $templine = '';
}
}
echo "Tables imported successfully";
$con->close($con);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Import sql file data with help from php code**

```
// sql file path
$filename = 'database_file_name.sql';

// Add this function into your helper file and add any where that you want to use
function import_tables($host,$uname,$pass,$database, $filename,$tables = '*'){
    $connection = mysqli_connect($host,$uname,$pass) or die("Database Connection Failed");
    $selectdb = mysqli_select_db($connection, $database) or die("Database could not be selected"); 
    
    $templine = '';
    $lines = file($filename); // Read entire file

    foreach ($lines as $line){
        // Skip it if it's a comment
        if (substr($line, 0, 2) == '--' || $line == '' || substr($line, 0, 2) == '/*' )
            continue;

            // Add this line to the current segment
            $templine .= $line;
            // If it has a semicolon at the end, it's the end of the query
            if (substr(trim($line), -1, 1) == ';')
            {
                mysqli_query($connection, $templine)
                or print('Error performing query \'<strong>' . $templine . '\': ' . mysqli_error($connection) . '<br /><br />');
                $templine = '';
            }
        }
        echo "Tables imported successfully";
    }

// Calling import menthod
backup_tables('database_hostname','database_username','database_password','database_name');
// backup_tables function have 4paramater - database hostname, username, password and database name that you want import sql data.
```

**If you want to backup/export database from php script**

```
// Call the backup_tables for export the database
backup_tables('hostname','UserName','pass','databses_name');
    
function backup_tables($host,$user,$pass,$name,$tables = '*'){
        $link = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
        
        mysqli_select_db($link,$name);
        //get all of the tables
        if($tables == '*'){
            $tables = array();
            $result = mysqli_query($link,'SHOW TABLES');
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
            {
                $tables[] = $row[0];
            }
        }else{
            $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',',$tables);
        }

        $return = '';
        foreach($tables as $table)
        {
            $result = mysqli_query($link,'SELECT * FROM '.$table);
            $num_fields = mysqli_num_fields($result);
            $row_query = mysqli_query($link,'SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table);
            $row2 = mysqli_fetch_row($row_query);
            $return.= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n";

            for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
            {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
                {
                    $return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
                    for($j=0; $j < $num_fields; $j++) 
                    {
                        $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
                        $row[$j] = str_replace("\n", '\n', $row[$j]);
                        if (isset($row[$j])) { 
                            $return.= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; 
                        } else { 
                            $return.= '""'; 
                        }
                        if ($j < ($num_fields-1)) { $return.= ','; }
                    }
                    $return.= ");\n";
                }
            }
            $return.="\n\n\n";
        }

        //save file
        $handle = fopen('backup-'.date("d_m_Y__h_i_s_A").'-'.(md5(implode(',',$tables))).'.sql','w+');
        fwrite($handle,$return);
        fclose($handle);
    }
```

Comment: ANy change of an explanation of what your script does and how it works?

Answer (score -1):

```
function restoreDatabase($db_name,$file_path)
{

    //checking valid extension file
    $path_parts = pathinfo($file_path);
    $ext_file = $path_parts['extension'];
    $filename = $path_parts['basename'];

    if($ext_file == "sql")
    {
         $c = new Config();

         $confJson = $c->getConfig();
         $conf = json_decode($confJson);

         $dbhost   = "127.0.0.1";
         $dbuser   = $conf->db_username;  
         $dbpwd    = $conf->db_password;
         $dbname   = $db_name;   

         $dumpfile = $file_path;

         $is_file = file_exists($file_path);
         if($is_file == TRUE)
         {

             //passthru("/usr/bin/mysqldump --opt --host=$dbhost --user=$dbuser --password=$dbpwd $dbname < $dumpfile");

             //passthru("tail -1 $dumpfile");
             system('mysql --user='.$dbuser.' --password='.$dbpwd.' '.$db_name.' < '.$file_path);
             return "Database was restored from $filename ";

         }
         else 
         {
             return "Restore database was aborted due ".$filename." does not exist!";
         }


    }
    else
    {
        return "Invalid file format.Require sql file to restore this ".$db_name." database. ".$filename." is not sql file format\n(eg. mybackupfile.sql).";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As we all know MySQL was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0 [ref](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) so I have converted accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19752106/815003) to mysqli.

```
<?php
// Name of the file
$filename = 'db.sql';
// MySQL host
$mysql_host = 'localhost';
// MySQL username
$mysql_username = 'root';
// MySQL password
$mysql_password = '123456';
// Database name
$mysql_database = 'mydb';

$connection = mysqli_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_username,$mysql_password,$mysql_database) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

// Temporary variable, used to store current query
$templine = '';
// Read in entire file
$lines = file($filename);
// Loop through each line
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
// Skip it if it's a comment
if (substr($line, 0, 2) == '--' || $line == '')
    continue;

// Add this line to the current segment
$templine .= $line;
// If it has a semicolon at the end, it's the end of the query
if (substr(trim($line), -1, 1) == ';')
{
    // Perform the query
    mysqli_query($connection,$templine) or print('Error performing query \'<strong>' . $templine . '\': ' . mysqli_error($connection) . '<br /><br />');
    // Reset temp variable to empty
    $templine = '';
}
}
 echo "Tables imported successfully";
?>
```

Comment: This is commendable, but the reality is this is a terrible approach. I do not recommend and I have to downvote. Use MySQL backup functionality instead or multi_query (careful)

Answer (score -2):

I use this code and RUN SUCCESS FULL:

```
$filename = 'apptoko-2016-12-23.sql'; //change to ur .sql file
                            $handle = fopen($filename, "r+");
                            $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));

                            $sql = explode(";",$contents);// 
                            foreach($sql as $query){
                                $result=mysql_query($query);
                                if ($result){
                                 echo '<tr><td><BR></td></tr>';
                                 echo '<tr><td>' . $query . ' <b>SUCCESS</b></td></tr>';
                                 echo '<tr><td><BR></td></tr>';
                                }
                            }
                            fclose($handle);
```

Comment: This won't work if any of the values contained a `;`

Answer (score -2):

Solution special chars

```
 $link=mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass) OR die('connecting to host: '.$dbHost.' failed: '.mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbName) OR die('select db: '.$dbName.' failed: '.mysql_error());

//charset important
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. As far as I see, the code doesn't read from any dump, nor does it insert anything

Answer (score -2):

I Thing you can Try this Code, It's Run for my Case:

```html
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'NOTSHOWN', 'test');

$filename = 'dbbackupmember.sql';
$handle = fopen($filename, 'r+');
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));

$sql = explode(";", $contents);
foreach ($sql as $query) {
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
 if ($result) {
  echo "<tr><td><br></td></tr>";
  echo "<tr><td>".$query."</td></tr>";
  echo "<tr><td><br></td></tr>";
 }
}

fclose($handle);
echo "success";


?>
```

Comment: This won't work if any of the values contained a `;`