# Openshift: how import database to MySQL via RHC or SSH?

Tags: mysql, database, web-applications, ssh, openshift

I have Openshift based scalable webapp with free account so I can't create phpmyadmin cartrige. Is there a way to import database to MySQL via RHC or SSH ?

Comment: https://www.openshift.com/developers/remote-access

Comment: Hope running this php file might help.
  http://stackoverflow.com/a/19752106/1982354

Comment: Thanks, have not tried, but found a better way to do this through MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of good options for doing this.

1.)  You can use the rhc port-forward command to connect to your database from your local workstation, then you can use mysql workbench or the mysql command line tool on your local workstation to import the database.

2.)  Use the rhc scp command to transfer your .sql file to your gear (place it in your $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR) and then use the rhc ssh command to connect to your gear and then use the mysql command line utility to import your database.