# how to import mysql database in codeiginter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Is there a way to insert data from a file into mysql database in codeigniter? I am currently stuck in this part. help please. I have searched in the net but I could not understand it and i really don't know how to start this function. please help....

Comment: which file data to import into MySQL database?

Comment: .sql file please help me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31577793/3494790 :  this is the solution