# How do i do a mysqldump in lighttpd? using php

Tags: php, mysql, lighttpd

I'm trying to export and import database in lighttpd using php. Mysqldump does not work as is:

```
$command= 'mysqldump -h localhost -u root -pXXXX db_name > backup.sql';
exec($command);
```

Comment: Is a mysql client installed on the machine you are running this command from? What is the output of exec?

Comment: the sql file is blank, i was looking for mysqldump exc file in lighttpd directories but have yet to find it

Comment: its installed on a minix mini device through the palapa webserver

Comment: I meant what is the output of the exec function call, not your command. http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php The output of the actual exec function should contain an error message for what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Palapa Webserver and it turns out the mysqldump application is not included. Sorry, should have checked this first and I also should have been clear that I was using Palapa Webserver.

I just ended up using import and export functions that I found.

Import:

[how to import .sql file in mysql database using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19751354/how-to-import-sql-file-in-mysql-database-using-php)

Export:

http://davidwalsh.name/backup-mysql-database-php

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download it from browser just use [`passthru`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php)

```
passthru('mysqldump -h localhost -u root -pXXXX db_name');
```