# how to import .sql file in mysql databse with php

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to import .sql file into mysql database using php but I can't

Am using like this code:

```
<?php

$sql = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '123123', '');
mysqli_query($sql, "USE vmail");
mysqli_query($sql, "source insert.sql");
mysqli_close($sql);

echo ("Done")


?>
```

How can I import it??

thnx.

Comment: Duplicate of [how to import .sql file in mysql database using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19751354/how-to-import-sql-file-in-mysql-database-using-php)

Comment: looks like duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19751354/how-to-import-sql-file-in-mysql-database-using-php

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this code. You have to read the sql file first and than execute:

eg:

```
$sqlSource = file_get_contents('insert.sql');

mysqli_multi_query($sql,$sqlSource);
```

Comment: Will this work when file contains comments or empty lines ?