# Import .sql file to mysql database

Tags: php

I am trying to import a .sql file to mysql database. The size of mysql file is around 90MB.

I also found a similar question [how to import .sql file in mysql database using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19751354/how-to-import-sql-file-in-mysql-database-using-php)

I am using [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19751354/how-to-import-sql-file-in-mysql-database-using-php) which is similar to the other one

```
$mysqlDatabaseName = 'db_test';
$mysqlUserName = 'db_dev';
$mysqlPassword = '1234abcd';
$mysqlHostName = 'localhost';
$mysqlImportFilename = 'dbbackup.sql';
$command = 'mysql -h' .$mysqlHostName .' -u' .$mysqlUserName .' -p' .$mysqlPassword .' ' .$mysqlDatabaseName .' < ' .$mysqlImportFilename;
    exec($command,$output = array(),$worked);
    switch($worked){
        case 0:
            echo "Import file ".$mysqlImportFilename." successfully imported to database ".mysqlDatabaseName.";
        break;
        case 1:
            echo 'There was an error during import. Please make sure the import file is saved in the same folder as this script.';
        break;
    }
```

I am getting the following error

> There was an error during import. Please make sure the import file is saved in the same folder as this script.

How can i fix it ??

Comment: What does `$output` contain? (That error is from the script: clearly whomever wrote it through that was the only reason it could fail.)

Comment: can you var_dump the return of 'which mysql' command and give it here ? maybe your mysql executable isnt in your PATH

Comment: as i tried with sample data it works for the above code...

When already data exist in the database, case 1 will execute in my opinion

Comment: @jagadeesh, you mean that the database should not be present there prior to running the script ??

Comment: Do you absolutely have to use PHP to import the file? It would be so much easier to use the command line or even *PHPMyAdmin* which has an upload feature

Comment: @illusion, nope database must present with no tables

Comment: @Phil.. I have to use php. My Clients wants a button which when clicked will copy the live database to a development database. In this way he can have a back up whenever he wants.

Comment: As far as I know, the above script is not working due to the large size of the database.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file system path of your dump file and place it in this line of the code your regarded:

```
$mysqlImportFilename = '/path/to/the/file/dbbackup.sql';
```

For large size: Increase your some of your PHP settings, php.ini, such as [memory limit](http://tutorials.hostucan.net/how-to-increase-php-memory-limit/) and [maximum execution time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829403/how-to-increase-the-timeout-in-php)

Comment: @SEMSEM, I already tries this.
I added $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] and also tries with a hard coded path to the file. Relative, absolute, I tried almost every way. But still giving the same issue. may be the file size is large so it is giving that error.

Comment: Please update your question and show what do you have tried for the path of the file? By the way, what's the OS? @Illusion