# how to backup and restore mysql database (localhost) to cloud service in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, backup

how to backup and restore mysql database (localhost) to Dropbox in PHP
I try this save to my HDD Drive but how to save to online drive and retrieve from online drive and also show all saved datas using PHP

Comment: There are several topics on dumping a MySQL database to text files using php. There also are several topics how to copy files to dropbox using php. Combine the 2. The question as it stands at the moment is very broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First save the backup on server using the following code:

```
<?php
try {
    backup_tables('localhost','root','','database');
}
catch(Exception $e) {
  echo 'Error: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
    /* backup the db OR just a table */
    function backup_tables($host,$user,$pass,$name,$tables = '*')
    {

        $link = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $name);
        // Check connection
        if ($link->connect_error) {
            throw new Exception("Connection failed: " . $link->connect_error);
        }
        $return='';
        //get all of the tables
        if($tables == '*')
        {
            $tables = array();
            $result = mysqli_query($link,'SHOW TABLES');
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
            {
                $tables[] = $row[0];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',',$tables);
        }

        //cycle through
        foreach($tables as $table)
        {
            $result = mysqli_query($link,'SELECT * FROM '.$table);
            $num_fields = mysqli_num_fields($result);

            $return.= 'DROP TABLE '.$table.';';
            $row2 = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($link,'SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
            $return.= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n";

            for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
            {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
                {
                    $return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
                    for($j=0; $j < $num_fields; $j++) 
                    {
                        $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
                        $row[$j] = str_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j]);
                        if (isset($row[$j])) { $return.= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; } else { $return.= '""'; }
                        if ($j < ($num_fields-1)) { $return.= ','; }
                    }
                    $return.= ");\n";
                }
            }
            $return.="\n\n\n";
        }
        
        //save file
        $time=time();
        $file_name='db-backup-'.$time.'-'.(md5(implode(',',$tables))).'.sql';
        $sql="INSERT INTO `backups` (`file_name`,`time`) VALUES ('$file_name','$time')";
        if(mysqli_query($link,$sql)){
            $handle = fopen($file_name,'w+');
            fwrite($handle,$return);
            fclose($handle);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Unable to insert into backups database!");
        }
    }

?>
```

And now use Dropbox API to save it on your dropbox. For more info visit: [Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/start/php)

Finally, delete the file on server using `unlink()` method in php.

Comment: excelent answer thanks my friend. but error come like this what can we do 
( ! ) Deprecated: Function ereg_replace() is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\my Pawning Project\backup_restore\backup.php on line 44
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0035 263824 {main}( ) ..\backup.php:0
2 0.0036 264704 backup_tables( ) ..\backup.php:2

Comment: line number 44 is. $row[$j] = ereg_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j]);

Comment: Sorry was busy, anyways, change `ereg_replace` with `preg_replace`.

Comment: Warning: preg_replace(): Empty regular expression in C:\wamp\www\my Pawning Project\backup_restore\backup.php on line 44

Comment: Hmmm...K try `str_replace`

Comment: every think is correct but have an error in line 30                                       Notice: Undefined variable: return in C:\wamp\www\my Pawning Project\backup_restore\backup.php on line 30                                                           $return .= 'DROP TABLE '.$table.';';

Comment: $return .= this is an assignment operation but we have to initiate the variable before assign

Comment: Oops, yes my bad. Add `$return='';` after `mysql_select_db($name,$link);`

Comment: May I know why you have unaccepted my answer?

Comment: sorry no errors but it only backup my structure without data ....... before add $return=''; shows error anyway the backup is success. after add $return=''; the backup is failed but no errors

Comment: I have updated with the final working code. Please try and let me know :)

Comment: Thanks boss working well. and how to show all available backups and restore date

Comment: and another thing how to show "successfully backup" message if any "error show error on backup"

Comment: ok backup is ok but how to restore data

Comment: First get the file content using `$sql = file_get_contents($file_path);` and then execute it using `mysqli_query($link,$sql)`. If you want to check if successfully executed use `if(mysqli_query($link,$sql)){/*Success*/}else{/*Fail*/}`

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(db-backup-1468929842-a9c7765f16edf9e2e2eb8a865a0f9.sql): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\my Pawning Project\backup_restore\restore.php on line 9

Comment: line 9 $sql = file_get_contents($file_path);

Comment: $query = "select * from backups where time='$restore_data'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $file_path =$row['file_name'].".sql";
    }

Comment: I guess you are creating backup in one directory and restoring in another directory. If so, please make sure you store full path of sql file in database. As in instead of saving `db-backup-xxx-xxx.sql` save it as `http://localhost/my Pawing Project/backup/db-backup-xxx-xxx.sql`

Comment: no bro need to do online but now iam trying this local host but not working

Comment: Online or local testing, you need have proper idea (and security) of saving backups and loading them. So have a variable like `$base="http://example.com/backups/";` and now load normally like `$sql=file_get_contents($base.$row["file_name"]);`

Comment: Any further queries, try posting it as a different question :)

Comment: i have ask new question so please help with full code  [new question Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38484666/how-to-restore-backup-mysql-file-in-php)

Comment: hi i tried too many restore codes not working pls help to restore backup data

Comment: Did you try http://stackoverflow.com/a/19752106/3699054. If you are still unable to solve it, then let me try solving it using teamviewer.

Comment: code is working but error like this message "Error performing query 'DROP TABLE advance; ': Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails" when drop advance table i choose all tables link with foreign key

Comment: "mysql_query("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0");" i used this before perform the query section and turn on tables imported successfully message.... now its working