# how to restore backup mysql file in php

Tags: php, mysql, database-restore

I have backup successfully but now i need to restore that data in localhost j
my backup drive is C:\wamp\www\my Pawning Project\backup_restore
this is my restore code.

```
<?php
include '../Connection/connect.php';
$restore_data = $_GET['restore_data'];//file time
$base="http://localhost/my%20Pawning%20Project/backup_restore/";
$query = "select * from backups where time='$restore_data'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $file_path =$row['file_name'];
    }

$sql=file_get_contents($base.$file_path);
mysql_query($sql);

if(mysql_query($sql))
    {
    /*Success*/
    echo "Successfully restored";
    }
else
    {
    /*Fail*/
    echo "Error: Fail to Restore";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Side note: you should not use mysql_* functions. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Answer (score 1):

You can use [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) (or [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)) function in php :

```
exec("mysql -hHost -uUsername -pPassword database < ~/backupdir/backupFile.sql")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were to use Mysqli (recommended over mysql_*) you could use the following

```
$sql = file_get_contents($file_location);
if($conn->multi_query($sql)){
    while($conn->more_results() and $conn->next_result()){
        ;
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried this? How does it handle MySQL client builtin commands like `DELIMITER`?

Comment: I use this for an installation script that I set up for a client, so it does work as far as restoring a mysqldump backup for the projects I needed, but I couldn't confirm either way about the `DELIMITER` command, so that's something to look out for

Comment: If you have triggers or stored procedures in your mysqldump, the delimiter needs to change, since semicolons occur within the body of those routines. But `multi_query()` doesn't support MySQL client builtin commands like `DELIMITER`, so this method will fail.

Answer (score 0):

You're running the restore query twice

```
mysql_query($sql);

if(mysql_query($sql))
```

Remove the 1st and just do:

```
if(mysql_query($sql))
```

If your backup file contains many queries, this won't work. You'll need to do one of the following:

1. Execute `mysql` directly and feed it the backup file (see Pierre's answer)
2. Switch from `mysql_` to `MySQLi` functions and use `mysqli::multi_query` ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php))
3. Trnsform the file contents into an array of queries with `explode(';',$sql)` then execute the queries on at a time by looping through the aray (will be slow)

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute multiple statements with php `mysql_*` queries. Therefore you should first get fully qualified path of the file you want to use and execute a SQL statement:

```
$path = $base . $file_path;
$query = "SOURCE $path"

mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: Have you tried this? `SOURCE` is a builtin of the MySQL client. You can't run it as a query.

Comment: Is that so? If it is I'll delete the answer.