# Import .sql file to cpanel server phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

I want to import my local database dump to server phpmyadmin.For that first i export whole database dump as db-backup-2016-09-14 14.25.11.sql file.after tht i tried to import this sql file to my server phpmyadmin.Below is my code

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

import_tables();

function import_tables()
{
$filename = 'db-backup-2016-09-14 14.25.11.sql';
$mysql_host = '192.168.1.1';
$mysql_username = 'databaseuser';
$mysql_password = 'databasepassword';
$mysql_database = 'databasename';
$conn=mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_username, $mysql_password,$mysql_database) or die('Error connecting to MySQL server: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
mysqli_select_db($conn,$mysql_database) or die('Error selecting MySQL database: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
$templine = '';
$lines = file($filename);
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
if (substr($line, 0, 2) == '--' || $line == '')
    continue;
$templine .= $line;
if (substr(trim($line), -1, 1) == ';')
{
    mysqli_query($conn,$templine) or print('Error performing query \'<strong>' . $templine . '\': ' . mysqli_error($conn) . '<br /><br />');
    $templine = '';
}
}
 echo "Tables imported successfully";
}
?>
```

Here the hostname declared is my server IP address and username password which i given in mysql database username password created in server.For this im getting error like

[image]

Problem with the connection to server.If anybody knows solution please help me to get out of this problem.Thanks in advance

Comment: Those aren't your real connection details, right?

Comment: I'm not even sure why  you're doing this if you want to use phpmyadmin. Just import the file that you apparently already have. Or use the mysql CLI tool to import the file. There is no point in having this PHP code afaics.

Comment: In my application if the user working in local server after inserted all details simply on click of backup it should export from local server data and imported in server database for tht im using PHP

Comment: Look at the demo provided here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19751354/how-to-import-sql-file-in-mysql-database-using-php

Comment: Problem is I can import in local..I cant import to server PHPmyadmin. In above link also refered there thy tried to import in local only

Comment: This is not a problem with your code. Something is preventing you from connecting to your MySQL server. Contact your web host for details.

Comment: Image shows that you are running script on your local network (Windows). So, i think, that your local IP it's not in firewall or not authorized on cpanel's mysql server. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-client.html#error_cr_connection_error

Comment: first of all never use real details on any public place like your question

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should enable remote connection on Mysql database and its look like you are using cPanel than you should do it by `cPanel => Remote MySQL` and set `%` for all otherwise put accessing `server IP`

Once Remote access has been enabled than you can access,

**Note:** Some time it could be not work due to firewall port block so contact hosting provider to allow on firewall