# return mysql error in a variable using system function in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to import a database using system() in php.
It works fine when my sql file is correct.
lets say i have an error in the sql file(for eg. syntax error).
I want that exact error in a variable so I can maintain a log and alert purpose.

```
<?php
    $lastline = system("mysql -u root mydbname < /home/mydbname.sql ",$retval);
    echo "\nretval:";
    print_r($retval);
    echo "\nlastline:";
    print_r($lastline);
?>
```

Unfortunately I don't get any errors in return when my sql is improper
When I run the above code I get to see the errors on terminal but it does not save the errors in the variables.

Comment: Try `exec()`. It returns the output as an array.

Comment: I have tried it. No luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$filename = '/home/mydbname.sql';
$mysql_host = 'localhost';
$mysql_username = 'root';
$mysql_password = '';
$mysql_database = 'mydbname';

// Connect to MySQL server & Select database
mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_username, $mysql_password) or die('Error connecting to MySQL server: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($mysql_database) or die('Error selecting MySQL database: ' . mysql_error());

// Temporary variable, used to store current query
$templine = '';
$lines = file($filename);
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
    // Skip it if it's a comment
    if (substr($line, 0, 2) == '--' || $line == '')
        continue;

    // Add this line to the current segment
    $templine .= $line;

    // If it has a semicolon at the end, it's the end of the query
    if (substr(trim($line), -1, 1) == ';')
    {
        // Perform the query
        mysql_query($templine) or print('Error performing query \'<strong>' . $templine . '\': ' . mysql_error() . '<br /><br />');
        // Reset temp variable to empty
        $templine = '';
     }
}
 echo "Tables imported successfully";
?>
```

Maybe importing this way would work, not sure this is what you need but it should work.
Code from [How to import .sql file in mysql database using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19751354/how-to-import-sql-file-in-mysql-database-using-php)

---

You could use the `--force (-f)` flag so that MySQL doesn't stop and just log any errors to the console:

```
mysql -u userName -p -f -D dbName < script.sql
<?php
    $lastline = system("mysql -u root -f mydbname < /home/mydbname.sql ",$retval);
    echo "\nretval:";
    print_r($retval);
    echo "\nlastline:";
    print_r($lastline);
?>
```

PHP docs on exec() specify an additional 2 parameters for output and return value so maybe try getting both and one might include an error message.

Hope this helps