# PHP Import Large file of Query in MySql

Tags: php, file, mysqli, import

I need to import all the old data for backup but i have too many data that it cant execute all query like 2k of query in my .sql file. Some are executed but not 100% of all the query are executed. There are no errors showed after. I tried to loop it four times maybe it will execute it all because when i tried with no loop it only creates 4 tables but in the backup I have 9 tables so i clicked the button again and it turned out to be 8 tables on the database and on my 3rd try clicking it again it has now 9 tables but the data is incomplete.

[Here is a test i made for backup and recovery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2si6.png)

here is my code:

```
<?php 
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
for($c = 0; $c < 4;$c++){
    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','test');

    $filename = 'backup.sql';
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r+");
    $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));

    $sql = explode(';', $contents);
    foreach ($sql as $query) {
        $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
echo "Successfully Imported";
?>
```

Comment: What is actually happening? Do you get an error message on the screen? Have you checked your logs? How big is the actual backup file? Please read about [ask] questions here. Also note: trying to execute all of this code four times in a loop is not going to help at all; that's just a shot in the dark. It's a bad idea to add a loop simply because you don't know what's wrong with your code in hopes that it magically starts working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to import .sql file in mysql database using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19751354/how-to-import-sql-file-in-mysql-database-using-php)

Comment: This is generally a bad idea. Use phpMyAdmin or a CLI mysql client.

Comment: Since this is a one-time task (you hope!) I'd manually break the file up into manageable parts, write a basic import script, and upload multiple files at one time

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to do a database/table backup and restore from backup is to use [mysql command line tools](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/programs-client.html), e.g.:

Create a database backup:

`mysqldump -u db_user -p dbname > dbname.sql`

Restore database from backup:

`mysql -u db_user -p dbname < dbname.sql`

The same can be done with a specific table:

```
mysqldump -u db_user -p dbname tablename > tablename.sql
mysql -u db_user -p dbname < tablename.sql
```

If you really need to do **import in PHP** then try to add the following line at the beginning of the php script. Probably your php script is interrupted because of lack of output for a long time:

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
```

You may also disable execution time limit to run script as long as it needs:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

Comment: Right.  But perhaps he doesn't have CLI access or has some other valid use case for doing it via PHP.

Comment: How can i use that "mysql -u db_user -p dbname < dbname.sql" ?? Where will I put it ?

Comment: @Karlo, please take a look at [MySQL Client Programs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/programs-client.html)