# How do I ensure I caught all errors from MySQLi::multi_query?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, error-handling

The [docs for `multi_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) say:

> Returns FALSE if the first statement failed. To retrieve subsequent errors from other statements you have to call mysqli_next_result() first.

The [docs for `next_result`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.next-result.php) say:

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

Finally, the example posted in the docs for `multi_query` use the return value from `next_result` to determine when there are no more queries; e.g. to stop looping:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query  = "SELECT CURRENT_USER();";
$query .= "SELECT Name FROM City ORDER BY ID LIMIT 20, 5";

    /* execute multi query */
    if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
        do {
            /* store first result set */
            if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
                while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                    printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
                }
                $result->free();
            }
            /* print divider */
            if ($mysqli->more_results()) {
                printf("-----------------\n");
            }
        } while ($mysqli->next_result()); // <-- HERE!
    }
    
    /* close connection */
    $mysqli->close();
    ?>
```

I don't know the number of queries provided, nor do I know anything about the SQL that I'm going to execute. I therefore can't just compare the number of queries against the number of returned results. Yet I want to display an error message to the user if, say, the third  query was the broken query. But I don't seem to have a way to tell if `next_result` failed because there were no more queries to execute, or if it's because there was an error in the SQL syntax.

How can I check all the queries for errors?

Comment: Error handling would be different depending on how you configure mysqli_report(); How do you configure it?

Comment: @Billy Oneal, multi_query only generates one error because it breaks upon encountering its first syntax error.  After multi_query completes, check for an error.  It will be a matter of "Yes, there is one error" or "No, there are no errors."  For your reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715889/strict-standards-mysqli-next-result-error-with-mysqli-multi-query/22469722#22469722

Comment: @mickmackusa , I tried, with mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); If I use an SQL with INSERT command that refers to a table that doesn't exist, It gives me the same result as if the query was successful. The result I have goes from $mysqli->error and it has the following text inside: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Despite the code example in the docs, perhaps the better method would be something like this:

```
if ($mysqli->multi_query(...)) {
  do {
    // fetch results

    if (!$mysqli->more_results()) {
      break;
    }
    if (!$mysqli->next_result()) {
      // report error
      break;
    }
  } while (true);
}
```

Comment: i tried to use "while ($mysqli->more_results()) {...}" but it turned to be an infinite loop

Comment: How can I get the exact error where you have `// report error`? `$mysqli->error` is not set, since `next_result()` returns `FALSE` before hitting the error.

Comment: next_result() documentation says it returns false on error, but the cases when more_results() returns true but next_result() doesn't return true should be rare.

Comment: @BillKarwin I don't see how your answer can help to catch all errors from MySQLi::multi_query, or check all the queries for errors. Please, see my answer for details. I think the question has been changed since you put your answer here.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to catch all errors, check out the example you use (which is from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli.multi-query.html)).

This example only contains `SELECT` statements, which is not common for multi-statement scripts.

If you also use `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` or at even `SET` - it will work differently.

`multi_query` - Returns `false` when the first statement fails. FIRST STATEMENT - this is all we can control. All subsequent statements are a mystery. If it is not a `SELECT` statement - it will give an error on `$mysqli->store_result();` and we never know was it successful or not.

BUT:

If you wrap your SQL script on a transaction (`START TRANSACTION; ... commit;`), you can be sure: if anything fails, everything fails. This is good, as this helps us to see if "all fails".

To do this, just add in the end of your "`insert` - `update`" script a little `select`, if last statement returns data: all scripts completed successfully.

Use SQL like:

```sql
START TRANSACTION;    
  set @q=1;
  select "success" as response from dual;
commit;
```

The PHP function:

```php
function last_of_multi_query ($mysqli, $query) {
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); //After that all mysql errors will be transferred into PHP exceptions.
    $mysqli->multi_query($query);               

    do { null; } while($mysqli->next_result());

    $result = $mysqli->store_result();

    if (!$result){
        throw new Exception('multi_query failed');
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to catch **all** errors from `mysqli_multi_query()` because there will only ever be one error. If any of these queries fails, MySQL stops processing and returns an error.

If you have [mysqli error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439) enabled then you will receive an exception either from `multi_query()` or from `next_result()`. You don't need to do anything.

If you are using manual error reporting then just check for errors after the loop.

```
    } while ($mysqli->next_result());
}
if ($mysqli->error) {
    // Handle the error here
}
```

To receive the information about the processing of each statement in the list you must call `next_result()`. The response from MySQL will either contain information about pending results, affected rows or the error message. If your code doesn't fetch all responses you will get "Out of sync" error message.

Comment: OK, but then you need to figure out which query the error was reported on.