# How to get error message with mysqli::multi_query?

Tags: php, mysqli

Here's what I'm trying:

```
if($mysqli->multi_query(file_get_contents('file_that_contains_a_bunch_of.sql'))) {
    do {
        $result = $mysqli->use_result();
        if($mysqli->errno === 0) {
            echo $mysqli->affected_rows.' row(s) affected'.PHP_EOL;
        } else {
            die($mysqli->error);
        }
    } while($mysqli->next_result());
}
```

But it's aborting the loop early and doesn't print an error message. How do I find out what the error is?

Comment: You should be getting the error message in your `die()` call.

Comment: @MikeBrant: It wasn't hitting that -- that's the problem.

Comment: Why not use mysql dump from exec?

Comment: @JvdBerg: It's part of a larger script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Peter deleted his answer, but it hinted at what the problem was. I have to put the error check outside of the loop.

Below everything, I need to write

```
if($mysqli->errno) die($mysqli->error)
```

The `next_result` function returns false if there's an error on the *next* query, so it won't even enter the body of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

It may aborting the loop if you configure somehow mysqli_report, look for string like this

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

in this case, each time you'll try to do this

```
$mysqli->use_result();
```

you will have an error generated if there was no result, for example if there was "set", "insert", "update" or "delete" types of query.

Did you find the way to get the error message?

Comment: This was a couple years ago, but yes, I think so. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12287843/65387)

Comment: From my experience the "multi_query" returns true even if some of the queries failed, that is why - there is no point checking it you can eliminate "if" statement. But you can add something: if you use "START TRANSACTION;" and "commit;" in your  SQL scripts, you can avoid some problems. I mean, by default PHP does NOT start transaction for "multi_query".

Comment: mysqli::multi_query ONLY Returns FALSE if the first statement failed. from here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli.multi-query.html

Comment: I havn't got the simple answer, so I invented the wheel, please, see my answer on the same question here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395326/how-do-i-ensure-i-caught-all-errors-from-mysqlimulti-query/27394448#27394448

Answer (score -1):

use this code it work well

```
while ($conn->more_results()){
     $conn->next_result();
     echo $conn->error;
}
```