# Query with MySQL event

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, zend-framework, zend-db

I try to perform this query with Zend DB:

```
$this->db->query("
            CREATE EVENT turn_tonormal
            ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE COMMENT 'Return the calendar state to NORMAL'
            DO
            SELECT type FROM calendar WHERE id = 64;
            UPDATE calendar SET type = IF(type = 'OK', 'OK', 'NRML') WHERE id=64;
            DROP event turn_tonormal;
        ");
```

In phpMyAdmin QSL all go fine, and I create this event with if conditions before UpdatE
But from PHP I receive this error:

> Mysqli prepare error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE mind_calendar SET timeband_type = IF(timeband_type = 'PRENOTED', 'PRENOTE' at line 5

I think this is because Zend DB query execute only one query and I have more than one. How I can solve.

Comment: Zend DB does not allow you to perform multiple queries at once.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I run multiple SQL queries per call to "query" using Zend\_Db\_Adapter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395056/how-do-i-run-multiple-sql-queries-per-call-to-query-using-zend-db-adapter)

Comment: Thank you very much, multi_query works, but it work in the same way that do a multiple call to query(). I think shell_exec()  is better, but in this case i prefer change my logic and left the idea of use MySQL events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is to use a PHP script with a cron to do the job so you can drop the EVENT requirement. Keeps is portable as shell_exec() will not be possible on all environments and does not qualify as a 'good' solution if you ask me.

Comment: Thank you for answer, yes i left this way. Now i add a timestamp on first action and after when the item of need id go retrived i control if the time what i set are elapsed and do action.