# Something equivalent to "SELECT * FROM (SELECT table_name FROM...)"?

Tags: mysql, sql, dynamic-sql, mysql5

This query runs, but it produces the name of a table as a result, rather than actually selecting from that table.

```
SELECT T.* 
  FROM (SELECT tablename 
          FROM ListOfTables 
         WHERE id = 0) AS T
```

where ListOfTables contains `id=0, tablename='some_table'`, I want to return the same result set as if I had written this directly:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table
```

Is there a native way to do this in MySQL 5, or do I have to do in in the application?

Comment: Table names in SQL can not be dynamic -- you need to use dynamic SQL, which no one can provide a reasonable example of until you specify what database you're using.

Comment: Native way to do what? It's not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: What result are you expecting ? Please show structure and some content of table 'ListOfTables'

Answer (score 5):

To do this in **MySQL**, you need to create a [prepared statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) which you can only create from a [user variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html):

```
SELECT @tn := tablename FROM ListOfTables WHERE id = 0;

SET @qs = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', @tn);
PREPARE ps FROM @qs;
EXECUTE ps;
```

Comment: What about where `id` is a parameter?

Comment: I don't understand. Of course you can feed in the id value from your application like usual. You can even make the first query a prepared statement, too.

Comment: I need to make it all a single statement for PHP's `mysql_query` -- I'm playing around with it but can't find a way to fold everything together without a parse error.

Comment: This is because, to cite http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php, multiple queries are not supported. You have to use a different client API, make a stored procedure or find another solution, maybe in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345637/php-multiple-sql-queries-in-one-mysql-query-statement

Answer (score 3):

You need to use dynamic SQL to get this result (the below code assumes SQL Server, I can't speak for other RDBMS').

```
declare @tableName varchar(100)
declare @query varchar(500)

select @tableName = tablename
from ListOfTables
where id = 0

select @query = 'select * from ' + @tableName

exec (@query)
```

Comment: You'd need a cursor/etc for that to cycle through the list of table names

Comment: @OMGPonies I didn't think the OP wanted to cycle through all the tables..?

Answer (score 0):

Almost the same as @Shark's answer, except you also quote the name of the table to avoid syntax errors.

```
-- Using variables just for better readability.
DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(4000)

-- Get the relevant data
SET @Name = QUOTENAME(SELECT tablename FROM ListOfTables WHERE id=0)
-- Build query 
SET @Query = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @Schema + '.' + @Name + ''
-- execute it.
EXEC(@Query)
```