# Create Multiple MySQL tables using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create more then one MySQL tables using php but it gives errors and i can not sort out what is wrong with it.

PHP code :

```
$sql = ' CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mod_reminder_entries` 
  ( 
   `id`          INT(10) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
   `user_id`     INT(10) NOT NULL, 
   `entry_name`  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
   `entry_value` INT(10) NOT NULL, 
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
   FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES tblclients (`id`) 
 ); 

 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `second_table` 
  ( 
   `user_id`     INT(10) NOT NULL, 
   `fieldstotal` INT(10) NOT NULL, 
   FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES tblclients (`id`) 
  ); ';

  mysql_query($sql);
```

It gives the error, besides do not worry about the mysql connection. I properly connect with the DB and i have tested it, it is definitely some thing wrong with syntax.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `second_table` ( `user_id` INT

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Technical differences aside, PDO is much easier to work with.

Comment: Thanks for a vote down, but the CMS i am working supports mysql_* functions. I do not understand why people here are so fond of down votes when they do not even have some thing to use in the heads.

Comment: Are you all sure this has not been asked before? This sounds a bit like a questions that has been asked. Also @backTangent what is the Mysql error number? Please provide it.

Comment: Even it comes late, this might be more helpful: possible duplicate of [PHP: multiple SQL queries in one mysql\_query statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345637/php-multiple-sql-queries-in-one-mysql-query-statement)

Comment: I did not knew that the error was due to multiple SQL queries, otherwise i would not have asked it.

Comment: Sure it's possible if you skip mysql_query and instead use for example mysqli_query. Check the answers here that is for any multi query (not just create table) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16591831/is-there-a-smart-way-to-run-multiple-queries-in-mysql-separated-by-a-semicolon/ .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use semicolon separated queries with [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), this function only allows one query at a time!

You must execute your statements separately:

```
mysql_query("
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mod_reminder_entries` (
        `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        `user_id` INT(10) NOT NULL, 
        `entry_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
        `entry_value` INT(10) NOT NULL, 
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
        FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES tblclients (`id`) 
    )
") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query("
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `second_table` (
    `user_id` INT(10) NOT NULL, 
    `fieldstotal` INT(10) NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES tblclients (`id`) 
)
") or die(mysql_error());
```

Or better, use [mysqli_multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) -- which means you must switch to [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php).

Comment: how would it work with mysql functions?

Comment: Separate out the two `CREATE TABLE` queries and execute them one by one using mysql_query. Do not attempt to do a `split(";", $query)`.

Answer (score 2):

Just do what the error message says.

You can only execute **one** query at a time with `mysql_*` but [**please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: The cms i am using, unfortunately only support mysql_* functions.

Comment: @backTangent ok.... then I would advise changing CMSs, but anyway. you can only do one query at a time with `mysql_*`

Comment: I can't, I am freelancer :)

Comment: @backTangent: How does being a freelancer == bound to a specific CMS? Isn't the point of freelancer is that you can code in whatever way you want..?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: I hope one day a freelancer gets such a leisure. But at this time we have to work according to a client. The only leisure i have, is that i do not have a boss.

Comment: @Neal, What's the image all about?