# MySQL syntax for creating multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am having a some problem that i don’t understand and trying to create tables from a php file , so i created a variable and i added all the create statements in it so i can run a mysql_query on it , i keep getting an error that there is a syntax problem , so i echo the content of the variable and past it in the sql section at phpmyadmin and it word fine but if i try it from php it gives me an error as :

Error creating table:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Materials` ( `Id` int(11) NOT NULL
>   AUTO_INCREMENT,' at line 9

here is the string in the variable that i run the query on :

```
   // Create Tables Variable
$Tables = "";

// Create Students Table
$Tables = $Tables . "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Students` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FirstName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Age` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Major` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Image` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
);";

// Create Materials Table
$Tables = $Tables . "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Materials` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
);";

// Create Materials Students intersectons table for many to many relation
$Tables = $Tables . "CREATE TABLE `Material_Student`(
    `Student_Id` INT NOT NULL,  
    `Material_id` INT NOT NULL,    
    FOREIGN KEY (`Student_Id`) REFERENCES Students(`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,  
    FOREIGN KEY (`Material_id`) REFERENCES Materials(`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);";

// Create Pages Table
$Tables = $Tables . "CREATE TABLE `Pages`(
    `Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY(`Id`),
    `Name` varchar(50),
    `Conent` varchar(5000)

);";

// Create News Table
$Tables = $Tables . "CREATE TABLE `News`(
    `Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY(`Id`),
    `Title` varchar(50),
    `Conent` varchar(5000),
    `Image` varchar(100)
);";

// Create Notifications Table
$Tables = $Tables . "CREATE TABLE `Notifications`(
    `Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY(`Id`),
    `Title` varchar(50),
    `Conent` varchar(5000),
    `Student_Id` INT NOT NULL,  
    FOREIGN KEY (`Student_Id`) REFERENCES Students(`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);";
```

so what am I missing here ??

Comment: Are those backticks? Or normal quotes? 
    ' vs `

Comment: Each query must be executed separately.

Comment: What function do you use to execute your query ?

Comment: You should upgrade to a non-deprecated mysql API such as [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), which conveniently offers a method named [`multi_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) that allows you to execute multiple queries separated by semicolons.

Comment: somehow related:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023810/create-multiple-mysql-tables-using-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In usual way you cannot execute many queries, I would recommend to execute all of them like different queries, however `MySQLi` has an option to execute many queries at once, documentation and examples you can find [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).

Comment: So The Problem is Trying to execute multiple queries at once using mysql_query() , so i need to do each one separately or use mysqli::multi_query ( string $query ) , did i understand the solution well ?

Comment: @user Yes, `mysqli::multi_query ( string $query )` let to execute multiple queries at once. But you have to use `MySQLi` methods, instead of `MySQL`. However they are really similar, so you shouldn't find difficulties. There is a good example on the page I gave a link.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue seems to be passing a multiple-query into Php's single query function.

See this link for explanation.
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php

I suggest you either break down your statements and execute one at a time, or
use multi_query function instead.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "yourusername", "yourpassword", "test");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

if (!$mysqli->multi_query($Tables)) {
    echo "Multi query failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

...
```

HTH