# Relate different fields in multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose I have two tables in a database in `MYSQL`, namely

`Customer_image`

`Customer_details`

Now I want that the `ID` field in `customer_details` to show up as the `UID` field in `customer_image` table. And if I update or delete any record in any one of the tables, the related record should also be affected accordingly. If anyone could relate the fields through `php` code it would be great.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Multiple MySQL tables using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023810/create-multiple-mysql-tables-using-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly,  you should do it with MySQL's ON DELETE,  ON UPDATE methods.http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/

But if you really want to do it with PHP for some reason, create an array and store foreign key relations data in this array like this:

`[
    'customer_details' =>
        'id' => ['customer_image', 'UID'] 
]`

And while you delete a record from customer_details,  check this array to understand which tables' datas also must be deleted.

Bu as I said use this method if you really need to do it with PHP, otherwise you have to do it in MySQL side.