# MySQL query works when applied by Phpmyadmin, but not when applied through PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpmyadmin

I am trying to apply a trigger to an existing table and column through PHP.
When executing the PHP code, no error is thrown, but the trigger is not created.

My PHP code is:

```php
//file: migrations.php

// created_at column already defined in a previous migration
//...

$migrations[3]['message'] = "added created_at, updated_at columns on rate table";
$migrations[3]['created'] = "2015-09-05 08:28:00";
$migrations[3]['sql']     = "
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER rate_created_at BEFORE INSERT ON rate
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        SET NEW.created_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
    END |
    DELIMITER ;
";

// apply migration
foreach ($migrations as $key => $value) {
    // run the migration SQL for the current iteration
    $sth = $dbh->prepare( $value['sql'] );
    $sth->execute();
}
```

heres what **does** work

- Copying and pasting the trigger creating SQL into Phpmyadmin
- getting rid of the `DELIMITER` and `BEGIN` `END` statements
  e.g. if I reduce the SQL to

```php
$migrations[3]['sql']     = "
CREATE TRIGGER rate_created_at BEFORE INSERT ON rate
FOR EACH ROW
        SET NEW.created_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
";
```

It does run from PHP, problem is I dont believe I can run multiline statements without `DELIMITER` and `BEGIN` `END`.
I have tried

- escaping the delimiter character
- using different delimiter characters

What can I do to get the PHP to run the SQL with the `DELIMITER` and `BEGIN` `END` statements?

Comment: run the delimeter commands as SEPARATE queries. e.g. `delimiter/create/delimiter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you will have to get rid of those `DELIMITER`, just have the below code

```
$migrations[3]['sql'] = "
CREATE TRIGGER rate_created_at BEFORE INSERT ON rate
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        SET NEW.created_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
    END;";
```

See this another post saying same thing [PHP: multiple SQL queries in one mysql_query statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345637/php-multiple-sql-queries-in-one-mysql-query-statement)

Comment: thanks Rahul, that works! I wonder why MySQL doesnt think the whole trigger statement is not finished when not using a different delimiter character?

Comment: `DELIMITER` isn't part of SQL syntax, it's a feature of the interactive user interface.

Comment: This is why you can't use it at sqlfiddle, you have to use their menu to set the delimiter.