# MySQL multi CREATE TABLE syntax help?

Tags: mysql, scripting, create-table

I'm trying to write a MySQL script that creates several tables. I have:

```
CREATE TABLE `DataBase1`.`tbl_this`(
...
);
CREATE TABLE `DataBase1`.`tbl_that`(
...
);
... (14 more) ...
```

BUT, only the first `CREATE TABLE` statement is executed. I get no syntax errors. Erm, am I missing the MSSQL equivalent of `GO` ?  What am I doing wrong here; how do I get this baby to run all the tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The create table syntax looks fine. Probably the tool you use to execute your SQL just executes the first statement.

Answer (score 6):

How are you executing this script?

If you are trying to run it programmatically, you should know that the MySQL API only executes one statement at a time by default.  You can't string them together with semicolons and expect it to run all the statements.

You can execute each `CREATE TABLE` statement individually in a loop, or else you can run a script by feeding it as input to the `mysql` command-line client.

It's not as easy as it would seem to write a general-purpose script runner class in your application, because the full script syntax include many corner cases.

See examples of the corner cases in my answer to [Loading .sql files from within PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147821/loading-sql-files-from-within-php/149456#149456).

Comment: This is exactly the problem, MySQL Query Browser only processes the first command. I will mark @Florian_Gutmann because he was first and could use the points (as compared to 48K... jeez! are you contesting with Skeet?), gotta hook in the new fish with rep. : )

Comment: LOL!  No problem, @Florian was indeed first.  Yes, MySQL Query Browser's query interface is just like running a single statement from within application code, in that it runs one statement.  Query Browser should also have a "Run SQL Script..." menu option you can use to execute multiple statements from a file.

Comment: Scripting interfaces to MySQL only execute one command at a time. This is a good thing: it lessens the automatable impact of SQL injections. Some environments have an interface to multiple statements, eg. at C API level using `MYSQL_OPTION_MULTI_STATEMENTS_ON` or in PHP with `mysqli_multi_query`.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

use database_name;

create table a..;
create table b..;
create table c..;

Comment: Worse. No tables were created at all.

Comment: I can confirm this does create create table A but not B or C

Answer (score 0):

Are the tables referencing (e.g. primary keys and the like) one another?  Tables are created serially, so if your second table is referencing a table that is not yet created, it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

How do you execute your script ? 
If you do it from command line it should be something like this:

```
mysql -u[username] -p[password] --database DataBase1 < scriptname.sql
```