# Is mysqli_multi_query asynchronous?

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$databases = array();
$path = '/Path/To/Directory';
$main_link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD');
$files = scandir($path);
$ignore_files = array();

foreach($files as $file)
{
    if (!in_array($file, $ignore_files))
    {
        $database = substr($file, 0, strpos($file,'.'));
        $databases[] = $database;
        mysqli_query($main_link, "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS $database") or die ("$database 1" . mysqli_error($main_link));
        mysqli_query($main_link, "CREATE DATABASE $database") or die ("$database 2" .mysqli_error($main_link));
        $db_link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD', $database);
        //In here a whole database dump with scheam + data is executed. 
        mysqli_multi_query($db_link, file_get_contents($path.'/'.$file)) or die ("$database 4" .mysqli_error($db_link));        
    }   
}
```

When running this script it was done very quickly (returned to browser), but it was still running queries after the browser said it was done. Why is this?

Comment: what *it* was still running *what*, and how do you know?

Comment: Yeah I'd like to know that too... Queries shouldn't execute async. Even multi queries (?) because they too can have results.

Comment: @Dagon Maybe he did a `SHOW PROCESSLIST`... @Chris `top | grep mysql` wouldn't be acurate, because mysql daemons and processes are always running.

Comment: maybe, or maybe not, that's why i asked :-)

Comment: I was just executing show tables on various mysql databases and they kept growing (as my script creates tables and populates with data). It took a good 2 minutes after the script was done executing for the data to be populated into the databases.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[mysqli_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) supports async queries. See changelog on `mysqli_query`. [mysqli_multi_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) does not mention async on the manual page specifically. Only thing `mysqli_multi_query` does is tell MySQL to execute a bulk set of queries. It's up to PHP to wait for the results.

As your code stands, your sending a bulk set of SQL statements to MySQL and not waiting for any results. Only time your `mysqli_multi_query` will ever `die` is when the first statement fails. So, that function returns true immediately after the first statement and moves on to the next line. That's why the queries are executing after the PHP is finished. MySQL is still working. PHP has moved on.

It's best that you loop through the results of each statement before moving on with your code. The following will `die` if a query fails anywhere in your batch.

```
mysqli_multi_query($db_link, file_get_contents($path.'/'.$file)) or die ("$database 4" .mysqli_error($db_link)); 

do {
    if($result = mysqli_store_result($db_link)){
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
} while(mysqli_next_result($db_link));

if(mysqli_error($db_link)) {
    die(mysqli_error($db_link));
}
```

Comment: You don't actually need to store / free the result. An empty while loop is sufficient `while(mysqli_next_result($db_link)) {}`. See the documentation: [next_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.next-result.php), [store_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php)