# MySQL slowly processing multi statement query in a transaction

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

There are two problems that I'm facing on a live site when executing a multi query statement using mysqli.

**Terminology:** when I say `query` I mean multiple INSERT and UPDATE statements wrapped in a transaction. Roughly 5k.

**Issue #1:** The query is executed fairly quickly (just a few seconds) but the database reflects the changes in increments of 10 to 20. Almost like I'm reaching an insert limit and there's a delay involved.

**Issue #2:** Due to multi statement query I have to call `->next_result();` to free each one of 5k results. This process takes so long that the page eventually times out.

**Local setup:** Vagrant with PHP 5.6 + MySQL 5.6 the above issues don't exist and everything runs just under 5 seconds (there's a CSV import involved).

**Prod site:** PHP 5.5 + MySQL 5.5.55-cll.

I tried comparing global variables and nothing really stands out except `innodb_thread_concurrency` which was set to `4` in comparison to my local value of `0`. Updating the value on production site did not show any performance improvement.

```
mysql> describe product_filters_link;
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| product | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| filter  | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Any ideas where else I could look? Thank you.

Comment: Tough to say outright without seeing the schema or seeing your own `EXPLAIN` statements.

Comment: @Makoto I've updated my question with the table schema. I don't think the table structure has anything to do with the processing of queries since I pulled the DB from the site and imported it locally and I get lightning fast processing.

Comment: Check [php mysqli multi query asynchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6102968/6248528) It's hard to be more concrete without seeing the code, especially checking why the two setups might act differently. And a general note: there is rarely a reason to use multiquery, and almost never a reason to include 5k queries in it. You will also get a lot more control over your query(s) if you send them seperately (e.g. error handling, no problem with `next_result()`, ...)