# Run sql file from php code to insert data in a different Server

Tags: php, mysql

I want to transfer data from test server database to live server database. The data is in the form of a .sql file. So using php on stage server can I transfer the data using shell_exec();

```
$command = "mysql -u{$vals['db_user']} -p{$vals['db_pass']} "
 . "-h {$vals['db_host']} -D {$vals['db_name']} < {$script_path}";

$output = shell_exec($command . '/shellexec.sql');
```

The above code is not working. is there any other way?

Comment: Why do you need to do it via PHP? Can't you use the command line?

Comment: I would suggest you write a bash script that does the actual import and you execute that with PHP.

Comment: You could connect to the DB in PHP, do a file_get_contents and then execute it via mysql_query. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6607547/1337431

Comment: @Whiteagle but the live db is in different Server.

Comment: @Partha, you can connect to a remote MySQL server (you do not need to connect to your local server, you can connect to a remote host without any problem :]), you'll just need to open the MySQL ports on the firewall and allow the user access from that specific IP Address.

Comment: 'Not working' isn't very helpful, do you not have an error message to share?