# Import .sql file via PHP upload

Tags: php, mysql, database, upload

I working on doing a file upload in-order to restore a backup table (.sql format)...
The code below is for uploading the .sql file :

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

<font style="font-size:18px;">File to import:</font><br />

<input size='30' type='file' name='filename'>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload File">
</form>
```

After doing a submit, the following codes are :

```
set_time_limit ( 0 );

   //Upload File 
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
       if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) { 
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['filename']['name'])) {



$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$table_name = "items";

$backup_file = $_FILES['filename']['name'];

if(!file_exists($backup_file)){
    echo "File Not Exists";
}

$sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE '$backup_file' INTO TABLE $table_name";

mysql_select_db('MM_db');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not load data : ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Loaded  data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
fclose($handle); 
     }
     ?>
     <script>
     alert('Items Uploaded Successfully');
     </script>
     <?php  
exit();
       }
    }
```

When doing the upload , I receive this error :

```
Could not load data : File 'c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\data\MM_db\items.sql' not found (Errcode: 2)
```

Its like it did not find my items.sql file, although I've checked if its there or not by doing `file_exists($backup_file)`, but still I'm facing this problem. I think there might be something missing with the file upload code?

Comment: Please don't do this. You've got **zero** access control here. If anything you should be using [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) instead of rolling your own. Remember `LOAD DATA INFILE` needs to have the file on the MySQL server, not the web server.

Comment: @tadman Sorry but you are wrong, If i replace the `$backup_file` value into a specific file path - Example `C:/items.sql`  And remove the whole file upload ... It will work like a charm, but I like to take things more in challenging way !

Comment: That path has to be on the same machine as the MySQL server process though. Maybe that's the same machine in this case.

Answer (score 1):

LOAD DATA INFILE cannot execute SQL statements found in an SQL script.  It expects the file to contain text data with options for symbols as separators and delimiters.  It does not recognize SQL statements.

If you use LOAD DATA INFILE on an SQL script, then you only load the text SQL statements into your database, which is quite different from executing the SQL statements themselves.

If you need to execute SQL statements in a script, you can find code to do this in the phpMyAdmin application.  Duplicating this functionality from scratch is a lot harder than it sounds.  See examples about this in my answers to:

- [Loading .sql files from within PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147821/loading-sql-files-from-within-php/149456#149456)
- [Running MySQL *.sql files in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027769/running-mysql-sql-files-in-php/4028289#4028289)

The better solution is to execute a SQL script by using [shell_exec()](http://php.net/shell_exec) to launch the mysql client with the upload SQL script as input.

But @tadman is correct, this is a dangerous and insecure thing to do, allowing user input to send an SQL script that you execute verbatim.  You can't know what malicious queries they will include in that script file!

Answer (score 0):

I used `file_get_contents()` to access the file contents and executed the code with PDO.

```
    if (isset($_FILES['data'])) {
        if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) { 
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['filename']['name'])) {
                $db = new PDO('dns', 'user', 'pass');
                $sql = file_get_contents($_FILES['filename']['name']);                  
                $data = $db->prepare($sql);
                $data->execute();
            }
        }
    }
```