# Importing a sql file into a remote mysql db with php

Tags: php, mysql

New to php and mysql, 
I am trying to insert a exported sql file into a remote DB.
I am try this code from [1and1](https://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/scripts-and-programming-languages-c85099/php-c37728/importing-and-exporting-mysql-databases-using-php-a595887.html) but it is not working.

```
$create_install_db_server = 'testdb.example.com';
$create_install_db_username = 'test123';
$create_install_db_password = 'test789';
$create_install_db_name = 'test';
$sqlfile = '/home/path/to/localsql.sql';

$command='mysql -h' . $create_install_db_server .' -u' . $create_install_db_username .' -p' . $create_install_db_password .' ' . $create_install_db_name .' < ' . $sqlfile;
exec($command,$output=array(),$worked);
switch($worked){
    case 0:
        echo 'Import file <b>' .$mysqlImportFilename .'</b> successfully imported to database <b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b>';
        break;
    case 1:
        echo 'There was an error during import.';
        break;
}
```

Comment: What error specifically are you getting?

Comment: The code doesn't show any specific error, It's just "There was an error during import.", Anyway I can get specific error message?

Comment: " not working" does it cause your head to catch fire?

Comment: That is the echo your code is doing...but why not echo the error you're getting from running the command?

Comment: The $output is an empty array, so I am not getting any details about the error.

Comment: Found the issue, the localsql.sql file did not have sql commands, sorry :(

Comment: are you fix your problem ? bcz same thing for me i dont know how to do that. can you guide me

Answer (score 2):

@srikanth, I have an another way to do this, try this one

```
<?php
// Name of the file
$filename = 'churc.sql';
// MySQL host
$mysql_host = 'testdb.example.com';
// MySQL username
$mysql_username = 'test123';
// MySQL password
$mysql_password = 'test789';
// Database name
$mysql_database = 'Test';

// Connect to MySQL server
mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_username, $mysql_password) or die('Error connecting to MySQL server: ' . mysql_error());
// Select database
mysql_select_db($mysql_database) or die('Error selecting MySQL database: ' . mysql_error());

// Temporary variable, used to store current query
$templine = '';
// Read in entire file
$lines = file($filename);
// Loop through each line
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
// Skip it if it's a comment
if (substr($line, 0, 2) == '--' || $line == '')
    continue;

// Add this line to the current segment
$templine .= $line;
// If it has a semicolon at the end, it's the end of the query
if (substr(trim($line), -1, 1) == ';')
{
    // Perform the query
    mysql_query($templine) or print('Error performing query \'<strong>' . $templine . '\': ' . mysql_error() . '<br /><br />');
    // Reset temp variable to empty
    $templine = '';
}
}
 echo "Tables imported successfully";

?>
```

Hope this helps you. :)

Note: mysql usage is deprecated, instead you can make use of Mysqli,PDO like below.

```
$db = new PDO($mysql_host, $mysql_username, $mysql_password);

$sql = file_get_contents('churc.sql');

$qr = $db->exec($sql);
```

for executing big sql files my above answer is not enough so i suggest you to take a look at @Abu sadat answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147821/loading-sql-files-from-within-php)

Comment: If the sql file is huge, which option is better? The exec() or yours?

Comment: Good question @srikanth.. I usually prefer exec() for big files. You can look at this explanation [example](http://innovationalmind.com/wordpress/how-to-execute-big-sql-file-using-php-code)

Comment: I have edited my answer according to your question, go through it @srikanth

Answer (score -1):

Try the following things

- Do an echo of the command before you try to execute it
- Try running the command on the terminal - check if this is successful
- If it is successful, replace your exec with a simple command (like 'touch /tmp/abc.txt') and check if a file is getting created.

By doing this, you are trying to find out if there is a problem with your mysql command or there is an issue with the exec function in php

Comment: If your command line query works and the php exec does not work...

open your terminal and type visudo - find the line 'requiretty' and replace it with '!requiretty'