# how can I run mysql script in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql script need to run in php, I have try, but not success. Can someone help me out?

I also try using mysqli_multi_query, but it doesn't work either.

```
<?php 
include 'connection.php';
if(isset($_GET["action"])&&($_GET["action"]=="versave")){ 
$gp_name = $_GET['gp_name'];
$version = $_GET['version'];
$query_vers = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp SELECT * from `gp_info` WHERE `gp_name`= $gp_name";
$query_vers .= "UPDATE tmp SET `version` = $version";
$query_vers .= "ALTER TABLE tmp DROP id";
$query_vers .= "INSERT INTO `gp_info` SELECT 0, tmp.* FROM tmp";
$query_vers .= "DROP TABLE tmp";

mysqli_multi_query($connect, $query_vers);
header("Location: gp_data.php");
}
?>

<form id="verForm" name="versaveForm" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="versave">
<div>
<input type="text" id="gp_name" name="gp_name">
<input type="text" id="version" name="version">
</div>
<input type="submit" name="vers" value="Version" id="versave">
</form>
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php , Warning
This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the GET method, us $_GET to get the submit form data.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";
session_start();
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


if(isset($_GET["action"])&&($_GET["action"]=="versave")){ 
$gp_name = $_GET['gp_name'];
$version = $_GET['version'];
$query_vers = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp SELECT * from `gp_info` WHERE `gp_name`= '$gp_name';
UPDATE tmp SET `version` = '$version';
ALTER TABLE tmp DROP id;
INSERT INTO `gp_info` SELECT 0, tmp.* FROM tmp";

if(mysqli_multi_query($conn, $query_vers)){
    echo "query exicute";
}
 //header("Location: gp_data.php");
}
?>

<form id="verForm" name="versaveForm" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="versave">
    <div>
    <input type="text" id="gp_name" name="gp_name">
    <input type="text" id="version" name="version">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="vers" value="Version" id="versave">
</form>
```

Comment: sorry, but it doesn't work. I have try to use mysqli_multi_query, but it doesn't work either...I have edit the code. Thanks

Comment: it is a bit weird that when first time I use your code is fine, but after that I try again it doesn't generate in mysql =.=?

Comment: Hi again! I wonder you could help me again with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56341597/how-to-save-multiple-ckeditor-in-php

Comment: Hi , I fixed that issue. When you get a chance please have a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

Use PDO instead of `mysql_query()` (See also: [Loading .sql files from within PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147821/loading-sql-files-from-within-php))

```php
<?php

if(isset($_POST["action"])&&($_POST["action"]=="versave")) {
    $query_vers = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp SELECT * from `gp_info` WHERE `gp_name`= gp_name;
            UPDATE tmp SET `version` = version;
            ALTER TABLE tmp DROP id;
            INSERT INTO `gp_info` SELECT 0, tmp.* FROM tmp;
            DROP TABLE tmp";

    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'username', 'passwd');
    $st = $db->exec($query_vers);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqli_query` instead of `mysql_query`. It is deprecated in new versions of `php` and it used only 1 parameter. We didn't pass connection variable in `mysql_query`.

```
mysql_query($connect, $query_vers);
```

Update this line to `mysqli_query`

```
mysqli_query($connect, $query_vers);
```