# how to save multiple ckeditor in php?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have create a multiple ckeditor in php, it can display the panel of ckeditor correctly, but when I click update after adding something in it, it didn't save to the database.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["action"])&&($_POST["action"]=="update")){  
$id = $_POST['id']; 

$content = $_POST['content'];

$query_update = "UPDATE `correspond` SET content='$content' WHERE id='$id'"; 

mysql_query($query_update);

header("Location: correspond.php");
}
?>

<table>
<?php while($row_correspond_result=mysql_fetch_assoc($correspond_result)){ ?>
<tr class="table table-bordered table-striped"><form action="" method="POST" name="correspond_form" id="correspond_formJoin">
<tbody id="myTable">
<td colspan="3" align="center"><div contenteditable="true" class="myContent" id="content"><?php echo $row_correspond_result["content"];?>        </div>
<script>
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName( 'myContent' );
for ( var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i ) {
CKEDITOR.inline( elements[ i ], { /* config for this instance */ } );
}});
</script>
</td>
</tr><tr>
<td colspan="2"></td>
<td align="center">
<input name="action" type="hidden" id="action" value="update">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Update"></td>

</form></tr><?php }?> </tbody></table>
```

Comment: convert <div contenteditable="true"> to Textarea  after you can store into database example https://programmingtechnologyworld.blogspot.com/2018/10/wysiwyg-html-editor-use-ckeditor-to.html

Comment: You should be getting an error, because `mysql_query` does not exist.

Comment: Please use `PDO` or `mysqli_*`, not `mysql_*`. It is insecure and was removed completely with PHP 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save multiple ckeditor, you have need to pass the name attribute in array format. when you click on submit save the content value using the serialize function.

PHP code.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

if(isset($_POST["action"])&&($_POST["action"]=="update")){  
    $content = $id = '';
    $form_data = $_POST['form_data'];
    for($i=0 ; $i<count($form_data['id']); $i++){
        $content = serialize($form_data['content'][$i]);
        $id = $form_data['id'][$i];
        $query_update = "UPDATE correspond SET content='$content' WHERE id= $id"; 
        mysqli_query($conn, $query_update);
    }
    //header("Location: correspond.php");
}
?>
```

At the time of display unserialize content value and put in textarea field.

HTML Code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.11.4/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName( 'myContent' );
for ( var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i ) {
     CKEDITOR.replace( elements[ i ]);
    //CKEDITOR.inline( elements[ i ], { /* config for this instance */ } );
}
});
</script>

<table>
<tr class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<form action="" method="POST" name="correspond_form" id="correspond_formJoin">
<tbody id="myTable">
<td colspan="3" align="center">

<?php 
$sql = "SELECT id, content FROM correspond";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    //get the content form database and use unserialize method
    $content = unserialize($row["content"]);
?>

<!-- Change div to textarea and use the name attr as array format -->
<textarea contenteditable="true" class="myContent" name="form_data[content][]" id="content"><?php echo $content;?> </textarea>
<!-- add the corresponding id to update the content. -->
<input type="hidden" name = "form_data[id][]" value ="<?php echo $row["id"];?> ">
<?php
}
}
?>
</td>
</tr><tr>
<td colspan="2"></td>
<td align="center">
<input name="action" type="hidden" id="action" value="update">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Update"></td>



</form></tr></tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This div Converted to TextArea

From

```
<div contenteditable="true" class="myContent" id="content"><?php echo $row_correspond_result["content"];?>        </div>
```

To

```
<textarea contenteditable="true" class="myContent" id="content"><?php echo $row_correspond_result["content"];?> </textarea>
```

Comment: thanks, but when I change to textarea, the ckeditor panel doesn't show, any recommedation?

Comment: CKEDITOR.replace(elements[ i ], { /* config for this instance */ } );     like example because you are using multiple editors CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
 CKEDITOR.replace('editor2');